# Node 6 running significantly faster than node 8 in Google Cloud Functions accessing Google Cloud Storage

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to upgrade my cloud functions backend to node 8 because node 6 is being deprecated on GCP.  I've found that node 8 is *significantly* slower than node 6, to the point where my functions are sometimes timing out. The application I'm working on allows the user to upload photos to cloud storage, which triggers a cloud function that pulls exif data off the photos and stores them in the DB.

To simplify the problem, I wrote a tester cloud function that shows the disparity between node 6 and 8.  The tester is triggered by the photo upload, and then simply downloads a file from a different bucket. Below are the programs and the command I used to deploy them:

Node 6 test:

```
const Storage = require('@google-cloud/storage');

bucketName = 'MY_BUCKET_NAME'
fileName = 'db-config.json'

/**
 * Generic background Cloud Function to be triggered by Cloud Storage.
 *
 * @param {object} event The Cloud Functions event.
 * @param {function} callback The callback function.
 */
exports.node8Test = (event, callback) => {

    const storage = new Storage({
        projectId: process.env.GCP_PROJECT
    });

    var start = Date.now()
    storage.bucket(bucketName).file(fileName).download().then((config) => {
        console.log(Date.now() - start)
        callback()
    });
  };
```

Node 6 deploy command:

```
gcloud functions deploy node8Test --trigger-resource MY_BUCKET_NAME --trigger-event google.storage.object.finalize  --runtime=nodejs6 --timeout=450s
```

Node 8 test:

```
const Storage = require('@google-cloud/storage');

bucketName = 'MY_BUCKET_NAME'
fileName = 'db-config.json'

/**
 * Generic background Cloud Function to be triggered by Cloud Storage.
 *
 * @param {object} data The event payload.
 * @param {object} context The event metadata.
 */
exports.node8Test = (data, context) => {

    const storage = new Storage({
        projectId: process.env.GCP_PROJECT
    });

    var start = Date.now()
    storage.bucket(bucketName).file(fileName).download().then((config) => {
        console.log(Date.now() - start)
    });
  };
```

Node 8 deploy command:

```
gcloud functions deploy node8Test --trigger-resource MY_BUCKET_NAME --trigger-event google.storage.object.finalize  --runtime=nodejs8 --timeout=450s
```

Here are my results:

- The node 6 test finished with an average time of **273 ms** (uploaded 10 items and averaged the times)
- The node 6 test never took longer than **550 ms**
- The node 8 test finished with an average time of **17,160 ms**, over 17 seconds (uploaded 10 items and averaged the times)
- The node 8 tests all took over **6,000 ms** with the longest test taking ***over 26 seconds***

How can I fix this?

EDIT: Added fileName and bucketName at the top. The file is a tiny plain text file that contains one json object with 4 properties, all of which are strings that define database connection configurations.

UPDATE: The original test data above was obtained using nodejs cloud storage version 1.7.0.  I have since run the node 8 test again after upgrading to the latest nodejs cloud storage (version 4.0.0) and am still seeing the same slow response times.  Another thing to add: the 'db-config.json' file is being downloaded in all of my other 20-some backend cloud functions.  However, these cloud functions are triggered by http and are as fast on node 8 as they are on node 6.  It seems that the node 8 slow down *only occurs in cloud functions triggered by a cloud storage upload.*

******************** **UPDATE: SOLVED** ***********************

I was not returning the promise in my node 8 code.  Here is the updated code with expected performance

```
const Storage = require('@google-cloud/storage');

bucketName = 'MY_BUCKET_NAME'
fileName = 'db-config.json'

/**
 * Generic background Cloud Function to be triggered by Cloud Storage.
 *
 * @param {object} data The event payload.
 * @param {object} context The event metadata.
 */
exports.node8Test = (data, context) => {

    const storage = new Storage({
        projectId: process.env.GCP_PROJECT
    });

    var start = Date.now()
    return storage.bucket(bucketName).file(fileName).download().then((config) => 
    {
        console.log(Date.now() - start)
    });
  };
```

Comment: Likely a small thing ... but in your sample code, can you include where fileName is being set?  I was thinking about running a test and by reading the code, couldn't see where filename was being set.  What size were the files being tested.

Comment: what version of the storage nodejs module is being installed?

Comment: I'm using version cloud storage version 1.7.0

Comment: I did not experience such an increase in Cloud Function execution times using the Node.JS version 8 runtime. By looking at the logs, the code executed with Node.JS 6 took over 700 ms for me on average and 350 ms the one with Node.JS 8. Both using version 1.7.0 of the Cloud Storage library for Node.JS and triggered by an Object Finalize/Create. Could you give some details on your Cloud Storage bucket's configuration? I.e its location, location type, access control...?

Comment: @Maxim Location type: Region,
Location: us-central1 (Iowa),
Access control: Permissions set at object-level (ACL) and bucket-level (IAM)